# CSS: "float:bottom" if vertical space available. "float:left" otherwise

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have two quite narrow (width:400 px) divs that should be stacked vertically if there is sufficient vertical space in the browser window. If the browser height is too small and there is space enough to the right, the "bottom div" should float to the right of the top div.

In a sense I'm asking for the opposite to "float:left". float:left align divs horizontally if there is sufficient horizontal space in the browser window and only float divs below the others if there only is available space below them.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: What if there's space on right and also space on bottom ?

Comment: Don't think there is a way to do this with only CSS. I think you'll probably have to involve some Javascript. Have the JS test for the window height onresize and then calculate how much space there is. Then apply a style appropriately to each div (`float: left;` and/or `clear: both;`)

Comment: Jashwant: putting the div below the other is always preferred. So it's only in the case that there's space to the right but not at the bottom, that div2 should go to the right of div1.

Comment: Thanks David. I was hoping for something simpler, but at least it sounds doable! If no pure CSS/HTML solution comes up and you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the level of browser support you require, a simple media query may solve your problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            /* SET THE DEFAULT RULES FOR SHORT SCREENS */
            .bottom-floaty {
                height:200px;
                width: 400px;
                margin: 15px; padding: 10px;
                outline: 1px dashed #aaf;
                }
            /* HERE FOLLOWS THE MAGICAL MEDIA QUERY FOR TALL SCREENS */
            @media all and (max-height: 500px) {
                .bottom-floaty { float:left; }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bottom-floaty">
            I'm a sometimes floaty div
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-floaty">
            I'm also a sometimes floaty div
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the effect I see with that:
[image: In a tall window]
[image: In a short window]

The CSS3 media queries let you set any rules css you like based on the viewport height. [The w3c has lots of information about media queries.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#height)

A relevant snippet regarding viewport height:

> The ‘height’ media feature describes the height of the targeted display area of the output device. For continuous media, this is the height of the viewport including the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any). For paged media, this is the height of the page box.
>
> A specified  cannot be negative.

Sometimes I find the Mozilla Developer Network a bit more accessible, but in this case they provide [basically the same information](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Media_queries#height).

Do you need to support old browsers who can't render media queries? It should be fairly simple to write a javascript [polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/) can have the same effect, especially using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**Edit**

I revised my code example to more closely match your problem. You commented:

> Jashwant: putting the div below the other is always preferred. So it's only in the case that there's space to the right but not at the bottom, that div2 should go to the right of div1. – Jonas

And I also set the widths to 400px as in your example.

Now it only floats left if the screen is too short for them to be vertical *and* there is sufficient room on the right to fit both. Otherwise it's always vertical.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Phil! Then there were a beautiful solution after all. I would upvote this answer three times if I could. Very thorough and to-the-point.

Answer (score 3):

if you dont want to use `float:left;` property, your every DIV goes down to the new line. so use the float left property. when you want new line just use `clear:both;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Sara. However, it does not solve the problem of wanting the div2 to stay at the bottom as default but floating to the right if there's no space at the bottom AND there's space on the right. It seems like one would have to build on your proposition with David's javascript suggestion (see comment on question).